# AutoCAD Lisp - How to get Y drawn vertically

Tags: lisp, coordinates, autocad, autolisp

I am currently using the following Lisp code to show the X and Y coordinates from the origin:

```lisp
(defun c:xy(/ pt pt1 pt2 x y  xy)

(setq pt (getpoint "\nPoint : "))
(setq x(rtos(car pt)))
(setq y(rtos(cadr pt)))

; x- leader horizontaal                                
(setq pt1 (getpoint pt "\nHORIZONTAL: "))
(command "leader" pt pt1 "" x "" )

; y- leader verticaal                                
(setq pt2 (getpoint pt "\nVERTICAL: "))
(command "leader" pt pt2  "" y "" ) )

(princ)
```

The script currently shows the Y coordinate (6050.00) as follows:

[image: Horizontal Y]

Though I'd like to have the Y coordinate drawn vertically like this:

[image: Vertical Y]

Is there any possibility to achieve this through Lisp? If so, what changes would I have to make?

Answer (score 3):

You can rotate the UCS as desired before you place the second leader:

```
(command "_UCS" "_Z" "90d")
```

Alternatively, use the _DIMORDINATE command instead of _LEADER so that the dimension text is associative and updates automatically.